# How to implement interface for an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created an interface named Student and it looks like below

```
export interface Student {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  Grade?: string;
}
```

Upon querying a postgres table, the data returned is

```
[
{"id":1,"name":"Tim","Grade":"1st grade"},
{"id":2,"name":"Tom","Grade":"1st grade"},
{"id":3,"name":"willaim","Grade":"5th grade"},
{"id":4,"name":"Henry","Grade":"4th grade"},
{"id":5,"name":"Bryan","Grade":"3rd grade"},
]
```

How do I make this array of student objects intact with the interface I have created?

Comment: When you create the object you can mark it as an array of Student objects, `var stu : Student[];` notice the `[]` after the type `Student`

Comment: While receiving, convert the type as `array as Student[]`